# Is there an elegant way to have functions return functions of the same type (in a tuple)

Tags: haskell, recursive-datastructures

I'm using haskell to implement a pattern involving functions that return a value, and themselves (or a function of the same type).  Right now I've implemented this like so:

```hs
newtype R a = R (a , a -> R a)

-- some toy functions to demonstrate    
alpha :: String -> R String
alpha str
    | str == reverse str = R (str , omega)
    | otherwise          = R (reverse str , alpha)

omega :: String -> R String
omega (s:t:r)
    | s == t    = R (s:t:r , alpha)
    | otherwise = R (s:s:t:r , omega)
```

The driving force for these types of functions is a function called cascade:

```hs
cascade :: (a -> R a) -> [a] -> [a]
cascade _ [] = []
cascade f (l:ls) = el : cascade g ls where
    R (el , g) = f l
```

Which takes a seed function and a list, and returns a list created by applying the seed function to the first element of the list, applying the function returned by that to the second element of the list, and so on and so forth.

This works--however, in the process of using this for slightly more useful things, I noticed that a lot of times I had the basic units of which are functions that returned functions other than themselves only rarely; and explicitly declaring a function to return itself was becoming somewhat tedious.  I'd rather be able to use something like a Monad's `return` function, however, I have no idea what `bind` would do for functions of these types, especially since I never intended these to be linked with anything other than the function they return in the first place.

Trying to shoehorn this into a Monad started worrying me about whether or not what I was doing was useful, so, in short, what I want to know is:

- Is what I'm doing a Bad Thing? if not,
- Has what I'm doing been done before/am I reinventing the wheel here? if not,
- Is there an elegant way to do this, or have I already reached this and am being greedy by wanting some kind of `return` analogue?

(Incidentally, besides, 'functions that return themeselves' or 'recursive data structure (of functions)', I'm not quite sure what this kind of pattern is called, and has made trying to do effective research in it difficult--if anyone could give me a name for this pattern (if it indeed has one), that alone would be very helpful)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a high-level consideration, I'd say that your type represents a stateful stream transformer. What's a bit confusing here is that your type is defined as

```
newtype R a = R (a , a -> R a)
```

instead of

```
newtype R a = R (a -> (R a, a))
```

which would be a bit more natural in the streaming context because you typically don't "produce" something if you haven't received anything yet. Your functions would then have simpler types too:

```
alpha, omage :: R String
cascade :: R a -> [a] -> [a]
```

If we try to generalize this idea of a stream transformer, we soon realize that the case where we transform a list of `a`s into a list of `a`s is just a special case. With the proper infrastructure in place we could just as well produce a list of `b`s. So we try to generalize the type `R`:

```
newtype R a b = R (a -> (R a b, b))
```

I've seen this kind of structure being called a [`Circuit`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/StephensArrowTutorial#Type_definition_for_.27Circuit.27), which happens to be a full-blown [arrow](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrow). Arrows are a generalization of the concept of functions and are an even more powerful construct than monads. I can't pretend to understand the category-theoretical background, but it's definitely interesting to play with them. For example, the trivial transformation is just `Cat.id`:

```
import Control.Category
import Control.Arrow
import Prelude hiding ((.), id)
import qualified Data.List as L

-- ... Definition of Circuit and instances

cascade :: Circuit a b -> [a] -> [b]
cascade cir = snd . L.mapAccumL unCircuit cir

--
ghci> cascade (Cat.id) [1,2,3,4] 
[1,2,3,4]
```

We can also simulate state by parameterizing the circuit we return as the continuation:

```
countingCircuit :: (a -> b) -> Circuit a (Int, b)
countingCircuit f = cir 0
    where cir i = Circuit $ \x -> (cir (i+1), (i, f x))

--
ghci> cascade (countingCircuit (+5)) [10,3,2,11]
[(0,15),(1,8),(2,7),(3,16)]
```

And the fact that our circuit type is a category gives us a nice way to compose circuits:

```
ghci> cascade (countingCircuit (+5) . arr (*2)) [10,3,2,11]
[(0,25),(1,11),(2,9),(3,27)]
```

Comment: This looks pretty interesting--I definitely plan on reading more about Circuits now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you have is a simplified version of a stream. That is to
say, a representation of an infinite stream of values. I don't think you can
easily define this as a monad, because you use the same type for your seed as
for your elements, which makes defining `fmap` difficult (it seems that you
would need to invert the function provided to `fmap` so as to be able to
recover the seed). You can make this a monad by making the seed type
independent of the element type like so

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
data Stream a = forall s. Stream a s (s -> Stream a)
```

This will allow you to define a `Functor` and `Monad` instance as follows

```
unfold :: (b -> (a, b)) -> b -> Stream a
unfold f b = Stream a b' (unfold f)
    where (a, b') = f b

shead :: Stream a -> a
shead (Stream a _ _) = a

stail :: Stream a -> Stream a
stail (Stream _ b f) = f b

diag :: Stream (Stream a) -> Stream a
diag = unfold f
    where f str = (shead $ shead str, stail $ fmap stail str)

sjoin :: Stream (Stream a) -> Stream a
sjoin = diag

instance Functor Stream where
    fmap f (Stream a b g) = Stream (f a) b (fmap f . g)

instance Monad Stream where
    return   = unfold (\x -> (x, x))
    xs >>= f = diag $ fmap f xs
```

Note that this only obeys the Monad laws when viewed as a set, as it does not
preserve element ordering.

[This](http://patternsinfp.wordpress.com/2010/12/31/stream-monad/) explanation
of the stream monad uses infinite lists, which works just as well in Haskell
since they can be generated in a lazy fashion. If you check out the
documentation for the [Stream](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.10.0.1/doc/html/src/Data-Vector-Fusion-Stream-Monadic.html#Stream) type in the `vector` library, you will
find a more complicated version, so that it can be used in efficient stream fusion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much to add, except to note that your `cascade` function can be written as a left fold (and hence also as a right fold, though I haven't done the transformation.)

```
cascade f = reverse . fst . foldl func ([], f)
  where
    func (rs,g) s = let R (r,h) = g s in (r:rs,h)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip--I knew I was displeased with the cascade function I had originally, but was putting off fixing it for other prior if off with a fold.